# how to make a effect (that i'll give a example with all the rest of the details). JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm new here.

Anyway, my and a couple of friends of mine have a basic knowledge in HTML, CSS, Java script and PHP.
So we decided to make our own website.
We still didn't decided about the subject of the web site, so suggestions are welcome :)

We divided the work to two different parts;

1. HTML and CSS, design actually...
2. JavaScript, PHP, all the technical things...

Now, we want to create an effect that will help you "know the ropes" in the page.
I'll give an example: http://www.wampserver.com/en/ .

You can see that when you click on one of the options in the bar menu, it scrolls down to the particular part that you selected.

How do I do it?

Comment: Looks liek their using a [jQuery plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1: Anchor Tags

All you need to do is give the element you want to scrolll to an `id` attribute, then code your link thusly:

`<a href='#idofElement'>Go to X</a>`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/bgs5c/)

[**More on `a` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

---

### Option 2: jQuery Animated Scroll

If you wish to animate the scroll, you can use, e.g. jQuery:

```
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/bgs5c/1/)

Comment: That wont make it scroll, that'll make it jump

Comment: @Jamiec - this is the behaviour in the provided example. Jump = scroll, just not animated.

Answer (score 0):

You can either get a jQuery plugin for scrollTo, or you can use the Native scrollTo method:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollTo (Native is always preferred)

Answer (score 0):

it appends a hashtag to the url, which will go to the element with the id of the hashtag,

so

```
    <a href="#download-wrapper" class="download" title="Start using WampServer">Start using WampServer</a>
```

goes to

```
<div id="download-wrapper" >
```

no js required at all